# How can I create a new column with two new categories?

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I am trying to create a new column named AgeClass with two new categories ("Juvenile" and "Adult") based off the HatchMass in a Tibble I formed. The "Adult" category is pretty much any NA value in that column. I have tried the following code:

```
    PBTdata %>% PBTdata
mutate(AgeClass = ifelse(HatchMass != is.na(HatchMass), "Juvenile", "Adult"))
```

I keep getting an output that has an AgeClass column but it only outputs the "Juvenile" category and leaves the "Adult" as NA. How can I change the NA values so that they are categorized as "Adult"?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `is.na` in `ifelse` directly. Try

```
library(dplyr)
PBTdata %>%  mutate(AgeClass = ifelse(is.na(HatchMass), "Adult", "Juvenile"))
```

Or in base R without `ifelse`

```
PBTdata$AgeClass <- c("Juvenile", "Adult")[is.na(PBTdata$HatchMass) + 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
PBTdata %>%
         mutate(AgeClass = case_when(is.na(HatchMass) ~ "Adult", 
                       TRUE ~ "Juvenile"))
```